# How to flter 70kHz signal with noise

Tags: filter

I am trying to filter a noisy 70kHz sinusoide that goes from -2V to +2V.

A factor 2 amplification should work.
Any suggestion on which circuit to use?

I tried to use an active bandpass filter using the [Texas Instruments filter online tool](https://webench.ti.com/filter-design-tool/)  but it does not find any opamp suitable for the application.

Since the noise is in principle a high noise frequency maybe a low pass filter would work as well, but since I am only interested in the 70kHz frequency, I think a bandpass filter would be better.

Comment: An amplification of 2 will just make signal and noise both twice as big. Try an LC low pass filter such as 22 uH and 220 nF - put 10 ohms in series with the inductor.

Comment: If you can't get a solution on the TI tool you probably picked way too high a Q (too narrow a passband).

Answer (score 2):

In the end the amplification was not necessary and a passive RC filter did the job.
Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Thanks for coming back and answering the question! It would be really great if you could enhance your answer a bit. State what R and C value you used, and, if possible, a picture or scope capture of input and output waveforms would be even better.